# ESB offering from Microsoft

Tags: esb

Is there any ESB offering from Microsoft that can work in Hybrid(on Premise & Cloud). Also looking for Queuing Facility where if the subscribers are down when the messages were placed is not lost.

Many of our WebAPI(REST Service) are protected and will require credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explored [Azure service bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-bus-fundamentals-hybrid-solutions/)? It has very good offerings for Hybrid solutions.